# Is This Statement True?

Tags: asymptotics

Is it correct to assert that $T(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ when:

$$
\frac{n^2}{\log{(n)}} \leq T(n) \leq \frac{n^2}{\log{(n)}} + n
$$

Comment: It is true that $T(n) \in \Theta(n^2/\log n)$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not correct according to [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) since the sequence $\left(\frac1{\log n}\right)$ is convergent to $0$ so we can't find $k_1>0$ such that
$$k_1\le \frac1{\log n},\quad \forall n\ge n_0$$

Comment: Is it suitable to say that $\frac{n^2}{\log{(n)}} \in o(n^2)$, then?

Comment: Yes this is correct.